# In engineering, should I assume that '...covered threads material...' refers to a 'composite material'?

Tags: перевод

In a English translation of a Russian engineering paper (on flywheels) I find the phrase 'covered threads' used to describe the construction. Should I use common-sense to re-interpret this as a 'composite material' ?

Example :
'...where Eth is Young’s modulus of covered threads material of housing...',

I suspect 'Covered threads' is a literal translation from Russian. In English-language engineering, 'Composite material' would be the normal form in this context (Composite materials are carbon-fibres or glass-fibre mats laid in a resin bed to form a solid material`).

The paper in question is:-
http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2014/ams-161-164-2014/galimovAMS161-164-2014.pdf

I have tried Google translate both ways and back; also 'covered threads' is too unspecific for useful Google search.

Comment: Welcome to Russian SE. I have to close this question, unfortunately. Basically, you are quoting some English text which is translated from Russian and asking whether one can guess what was the original term used in this supposedly bad/vague/inaccurate translation. Well, we can only guess and even if our guess will be good - it's not the way questions are stated here.

Comment: >> 'Basically, you are quoting some English text. ' 
 Yes that is exactly what I am doing. It seemed reasonable that a Russian/English speaker would recognise the phrase and be able to map it to the usual English usage. An engineer or car enthusiast would suffice. 
Could you suggest another source of this type of translation assistance? 
I could try for  a Russian penfriend...

Comment: Well, you can try to fundamentally edit your question: provide domain, provide exact English term, provide it's meaning and an example sentence, provide translations you got so far and ask whether you guess is correct and, if not, what would be a better Russian counterpart. This would be on-topic. Guessing term too vague and doesn't help other Russian language learners.

Comment: Also, here's article (from same group of authors with suspiciously similar title) in Russian - that might help ;)
http://ntvp.ru/files/NTVP_5_2016.php (check for  "Расчет напряжений в супермаховиках") (for some reason http: part is ignored, so just pate it to command line and add http)

Comment: @shabunc Thank you. I was technically misusing your SO site, which I chose because I was hoping to network with dual-language speakers having some domain-specific knowledge (in a narrow technical domain perhaps, but composites are an everyday constructional material even if people do not know what engineers call it carbon-fibre fibreglass or GRP are common usage among hobbyists). 
BTW I don't speak Russian but my sister once showed me how to write my name in Cyrillic!

Comment: @JKlen Thanks but I have the information I want from this and related documents. I beiieve my assumption of 'Covered Threads' == 'Fibre Composite' is safe enough, it is a side issue that I was curious about (I am always interested in how each language shapes its humans' thinking). Bye now.